# Webform HTML Email Fine on localhost with MailHog, Just Text on Server

Tags: webforms, emails

I Developed a webform on my localhost, testing the Email using Mailhog.  Everything looks fine, nicely formatted html emails.  When I moved it to my test server at A2Hosting, the emails all show as text.  Using Drupal 9.2.7, Webform 6.1.2.  I am not using any additional mail modules, just what comes with Drupal and Webform.

To move to my A2Hosting site, I just made a tarball, extracted, reloaded the database and got the site running. I do not know if Mailhog is just a poor choice for local email testing, if it is a problem at A2Hosting, or if I need some other module to make this work on the hosting site.  It works fine on my local machine.  The email header does seem very complex and I have included it below.

Note that EMClient says the email is formatted as html, but it show the html text.

Any idea what I need to do to get html email delivered from my hosting site?

```
Delivered-To: hummingbirdretreats@gmail.com
Received: by 2002:a67:e1de:0:0:0:0:0 with SMTP id p30csp745012vsl; Sun, 19 Dec
 2021 13:09:16 -0800 (PST)
X-Google-Smtp-Source: ABdhPJyMretpmTYP0W8WnE73MwAJmqWAs/sJzQf+2GGRxXLUNWB+ZTToY4dcwopzcjQX9LYHiRka
X-Received: by 2002:a17:903:2404:b0:148:db27:981a with SMTP id
 e4-20020a170903240400b00148db27981amr13552440plo.31.1639948156683; Sun, 19
 Dec 2021 13:09:16 -0800 (PST)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1639948156; cv=none; d=google.com;
 s=arc-20160816;
 b=nvnaX1XfnDvqdSZFi3oE8WHzEaA+58ovq9ABMbkwMZBXTGrEDONZktnFqbpIA29lsQ
 jnOes6zRpHNeqV+801eH9iJUx4OPG0GfiCFnY4EtKtMCqlTF40K1o3Pdt46rqOmX+oZT
 AvOpIhvE3RJcg6q4+6I32PCrha6ReIRyxaa77QUZ+6zuqEFxsgyksuYk8qZmBFXW4k2D
 dJ82XXO6AjeSE6+79dP8yWnKFUug7g066D9v6ZryB/mlLU94rfsf+g9mLVMiXlrXspi+
 vO98zo0mcylMN9hF6+KbM+BUWty4puvpbqfyMtSN4QQ0F/AUNrjWPyb472wfTz2vxIIs syWA==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com;
 s=arc-20160816;
 h=date:from:message-id:mime-version:subject:to:dkim-signature;
 bh=CyxsiqnaEZFERiXIhFvUgPo5A/uykwhLvxMvB5XFUqY=;
 b=nZIUHh1Ax6I7+2VPsHtxEJMhZeEDx9EzHx19ry2b4ZORdpLLIPpazKuVNPq+XAp5U3
 0nQFEbl9pDbV4irgvGIqCNNHPr+JtjlZ7YX03hx4zNFpfDeKxGBl5ackl91K2zzbzg4X
 DmXGyQpHywwgFK/zNlpTvpyAbq5wXi5/us4ZyE5ytzY5vzlrku1KApoM8tvrhzhEtLmT
 /gGaWIt1cFZFT3K1zZUOeExKgNt2MyL0FEfNrM62JnYL1yl3jcA+XdeHD090uQx17GLV
 zPxqQXsywU9VRJz9eMffllNvP4LoTdtGUTiRKGNF5rzQGaqIj8KKgi597MnwkAPhwYmD Ckiw==
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com; dkim=pass
 header.i=@hummingbirdhealingcenter.org header.s=default header.b=VLU1Jaup;
 spf=pass (google.com: domain of info@hummingbirdhealingcenter.org designates
 23.83.209.51 as permitted sender)
 smtp.mailfrom=info@hummingbirdhealingcenter.org
Return-Path: <info@hummingbirdhealingcenter.org>
Received: from dragonfly.birch.relay.mailchannels.net
 (dragonfly.birch.relay.mailchannels.net. [23.83.209.51]) by mx.google.com
 with ESMTPS id a22si8442075pff.212.2021.12.19.13.09.16 for
 <hummingbirdretreats@gmail.com> (version=TLS1_2
 cipher=ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128); Sun, 19 Dec 2021 13:09:16
 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of info@hummingbirdhealingcenter.org
 designates 23.83.209.51 as permitted sender) client-ip=23.83.209.51;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; dkim=pass
 header.i=@hummingbirdhealingcenter.org header.s=default header.b=VLU1Jaup;
 spf=pass (google.com: domain of info@hummingbirdhealingcenter.org designates
 23.83.209.51 as permitted sender)
 smtp.mailfrom=info@hummingbirdhealingcenter.org
X-Sender-Id: a2hosting|x-authuser|humming7@mi3-ts4.a2hosting.com
Received: from relay.mailchannels.net (localhost [127.0.0.1]) by
 relay.mailchannels.net (Postfix) with ESMTP id E6FCE881065 for
 <hummingbirdretreats@gmail.com>; Sun, 19 Dec 2021 21:09:15 +0000 (UTC)
Received: from mi3-ts4.a2hosting.com (unknown [127.0.0.6]) (Authenticated
 sender: a2hosting) by relay.mailchannels.net (Postfix) with ESMTPA id
 5FF62880BEC for <hummingbirdretreats@gmail.com>; Sun, 19 Dec 2021 21:09:15
 +0000 (UTC)
X-Sender-Id: a2hosting|x-authuser|humming7@mi3-ts4.a2hosting.com
Received: from mi3-ts4.a2hosting.com (mi3-ts4.a2hosting.com [70.32.23.71])
 (using TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384) by 100.97.65.154
 (trex/6.4.3); Sun, 19 Dec 2021 21:09:15 +0000
X-MC-Relay: Neutral
X-MailChannels-SenderId: a2hosting|x-authuser|humming7@mi3-ts4.a2hosting.com
X-MailChannels-Auth-Id: a2hosting
X-Wipe-Ski: 4c75bb0d555c23f2_1639948155748_4128232018
X-MC-Loop-Signature: 1639948155748:545827072
X-MC-Ingress-Time: 1639948155748
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/relaxed;
 d=hummingbirdhealingcenter.org; s=default; h=Date:From:Message-Id:
 MIME-Version:Subject:To:Sender:Reply-To:Cc:Content-Type:
 Content-Transfer-Encoding:Content-ID:Content-Description:Resent-Date:
 Resent-From:Resent-Sender:Resent-To:Resent-Cc:Resent-Message-ID:In-Reply-To:
 References:List-Id:List-Help:List-Unsubscribe:List-Subscribe:List-Post:
 List-Owner:List-Archive; bh=CyxsiqnaEZFERiXIhFvUgPo5A/uykwhLvxMvB5XFUqY=; b=V
 LU1Jauph2/wQjuiTs5ipSo6SMxn1AXD+B2JwT78QmstmyHDidi09umiRfXPcYJrI8+uYai0yMFhHk
 o3V4jTjgZ4vGAKHtiPYE+Pv0x6CYipWp5gwdrPNOuVCUb7q9MhvjhEgfs0zydC8GX8A6dBm6EyOH8
 jFeMrlzjQIKcBZ17lw6nMFze1CYswIjGvgK+98ilRTXAE9QoGvry9vPv0Wv8E2/LoVuXKesN/DTnI
 PQtjiHC/RcHFUGflr/z/YRpGaAJQsVLx/QUOBLoQf/iYN6Yc7l8p6qtaM7sZCaXo6yPCRDm0ahQtt
 OhfDuyn8/MmFEyK6BFXcbJTCUVTloWMFw==;
Received: from humming7 by mi3-ts4.a2hosting.com with local (Exim 4.94.2)
 (envelope-from <info@hummingbirdhealingcenter.org>) id 1mz3Qg-000x6T-BR for
 hummingbirdretreats@gmail.com; Sun, 19 Dec 2021 16:09:14 -0500
To: hummingbirdretreats@gmail.com
Subject: Booking Form for Loremipsum
MIME-Version: 1.0 Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8; format=flowed
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8Bit X-Mailer: Drupal Sender:
 info@hummingbirdhealingcenter.org From: HHC Booking Form
 <info@hummingbirdhealingcenter.org> Reply-to: HHC Booking Form
 <info@hummingbirdhealingcenter.org>
Message-Id: <E1mz3Qg-000x6T-BR@mi3-ts4.a2hosting.com>
From: info@hummingbirdhealingcenter.org
Date: Sun, 19 Dec 2021 16:09:14 -0500
X-AuthUser: humming7@mi3-ts4.a2hosting.com

<html>
<head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't you posted this somewhere else recently? I'm sure I answered this already. The problem is here:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0 Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8; format=flowed
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8Bit X-Mailer: Drupal Sender:
 info@hummingbirdhealingcenter.org From: HHC Booking Form
 <info@hummingbirdhealingcenter.org> Reply-to: HHC Booking Form
 <info@hummingbirdhealingcenter.org>
```

That is all on one long line. That is wrong. There should be a \r\n before each header field name. With everything wrapped like that, the mail client receiving the mail doesn't see those headers and thus doesn't know it's an HTML formatted email. It should look like this:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8; format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8Bit
X-Mailer: Drupal
Sender: info@hummingbirdhealingcenter.org
From: HHC Booking Form <info@hummingbirdhealingcenter.org>
Reply-to: HHC Booking Form <info@hummingbirdhealingcenter.org>
```

The reason this is happening probably has something to do with your server email software or your mail module. The RFC mandates that \r\n be used as line terminators for mail headers, but historically this is something a lot of people get wrong - they tend to use the operating system's native line terminator instead. That is wrong.

This was probably caused by [this Drupal Core bug](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3270647). All supported releases now have this fixed.